# SQL Pivot single column to multiple tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

For SQL Server 2012:

I'm trying to normalize my data into the first normal form via PIVOT then save the results to a table.
I need help on the PIVOT and saving it to a table.

Raw data is a daily or weekly generated .xls, I then bulk insert it to `temprmi$` table.

Raw Data structure is below - TNUM is a unique number to the whole company. There are more prompt texts than just these three (64 total).

Table: `temprmi$`

```
TNUM    EmpID    Prompt Text     TData
1       e001     fixture         506
1       e011     sheet           F1234567
1       f001     cweld           abcDFG
2       f031     fixture         510
2       f032     sheet           H7654321
2       e001     cweld           DFGabc
```

I have tried to use SQL `PIVOT` to get it into one table, which then I can break out into multiple (as defined below) but I am not being successful.

What I'd like to get it to be:

Fixture Table:

```
TNUM     Fixture   EMPID
1        506       e001
2        510       f031
```

sheet table:

```
TNUM     Sheet    EMPID
 1       F1234567  e011
 2       H7654321  f032
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I've added my `PIVOT` query for reference however it doesn't work. (output below as well.

```
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery2 AS nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery3 AS nvarchar(max)
--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','')
+ QUOTENAME([prompt text])
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [prompt text] FROM temprmi$) AS Prompts
--select @ColumnName
SET @DynamicPivotQuery ='SELECT [trav num],[empid],' + @ColumnName 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery2='   FROM [temprmi$]
PIVOT(min([TData])
   FOR [Prompt Text] IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--select (@DynamicPivotQuery+@DynamicPivotQuery2)
set @DynamicPivotQuery3=@DynamicPivotQuery+@DynamicPivotQuery2
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery3
select @DynamicPivotQuery3
```

Output:

```
TNUM    EmpID    Fixture         sheet
1       null     506             null
1       e001     null            null
1       null     null            F1234567
2       null     510             null
2       e001     null            null
2       null     null            H7654321
```

Comment: Is this a one-off migration task?

Comment: No - the Raw data comes in daily/weekly as a .xls and I bulk insert it to the temprmi$ table. Updated the question above to be clearer.

Comment: Are the 64 tables fixed? You need separate `INSERT` statements regardless of how you do things, it might be simpler to have the list in a helper table and then build a simple dynamic insert query around that

Comment: Yes the 64 tables would be fixed (or could be combined as reasonable). I didn't follow the "Having a list in a helper table then build a dynamic insert query around that" 

Could you explain more or give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output looks fine. You just need to make sure when you do your inserts that you only select rows where values are not null.

For Fixtures

```
INSERT INTO Fixture 
SELECT * 
FROM PVTTable 
WHERE FIXTURE IS NOT NULL
```

**EDIT**
I see you're missing the empId on some records.  I copied your raw data structure and built a dynamic pivot using it.  I could not duplicate the missing empId issue.  Maybe you're missing some information in your question.  Below is a working example.

```
CREATE TABLE #temprmi (
    TNUM INT, 
    EmpID VARCHAR(50), 
    [Prompt Text] VARCHAR(100), 
    TData VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #temprmi
        (TNUM,EmpID,[Prompt Text],TData)
VALUES
(1,'e001','fixture','506'),
(1,'e011','sheet','F1234567'),
(1,'f001','cweld','abcDFG'),
(2,'f031v','fixture','510'),
(2,'f032','sheet','H7654321'),
(2,'e001','cweld','DFGabc')


DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ',', '') + CONCAT('[', [Prompt Text], ']')
FROM (  SELECT DISTINCT [Prompt Text] 
        FROM #temprmi) AS t

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = 
'
    SELECT TNUM, EmpID, ' + @columns + '
    FROM #temprmi 
    PIVOT (
        MIN(Tdata)
        FOR [Prompt Text] IN (' + @columns + ')
    ) p
'
EXEC(@sql)

DROP TABLE #temprmi
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookup table to hold the tablename/column/prompt combinations, and iterate that with a cursor, generating a dynamic statement to insert the relevant rows to each table:

```
DECLARE @tableName varchar(20),
        @columnName varchar(20),
        @prompt varchar(20)

DECLARE @dynSQL varchar(500)

DECLARE cLookup CURSOR FOR
  SELECT * FROM Lookup

OPEN cLookup
FETCH NEXT FROM cLookup 
INTO @tableName, @columnName, @prompt

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SET @dynSQL = 'INSERT INTO ' + @tableName +
  ' SELECT TNUM, EMPID, TData AS ' + @columnName +
  ' FROM Input WHERE [Prompt Text] = ''' + @prompt + ''''

  EXEC sp_executesql @dynSQL

  FETCH NEXT FROM cLookup 
  INTO @tableName, @columnName, @prompt
END

CLOSE cLookup
DEALLOCATE cLookup
```

Look at [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6352e/6) to see more details of the lookup table